# Json string Deserialisation in silverlight

Tags: c#, json, xaml, silverlight-4.0, deserialization

I have a json string Like this:

```
{"0":{"City_Id":"2","City_Name":"Agra"},"1":{"City_Id":"3","City_Name":"Ahmedabad"}}
```

I want to deserialise it in c#  by any means possible.(Note: for silverlight 4.0)

Any kind of help will be appreciated,

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize the json string.

```
MemoryStream theObjectToBeDeserialized = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString))
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass temp = (MyClass)serializer.ReadObject(theObjectToBeDeserialized);
theObjectToBeDeserialized.Dispose();
```

By the way; it is better to wrap the statements with a `using`;

```
MyClass temp = null;
using(MemoryStream theObjectToBeDeserialized = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    temp = (MyClass)serializer.ReadObject(theObjectToBeDeserialized);
}
```

and the related class:

```
public class City
{
    public int City_Id {get; set;}
    public string City_Name {get; set;}
}
```

and usage;

```
List<City> cities = null;
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<City>));
cities = (List<City>)serializer.ReadObject(theObjectToBeDeserialized);
```

Comment: I have done this much I am having problem defining MyClass.
Can you show me how can I define an class for this json string.

Comment: @Mr.Wayne http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/29/DataContractJsonSerializer-in-NET-35

Comment: Thank you for the post!
The thing is I am having problem creating the Class for my json string type can you show me how can I create A class for this particular string cause I doesnot seem to find the answer to that?
Like Myclass in this case (Can you show me the structure of this Myclass)

Comment: @Mr.Wayne I think you need to create a class with an integer property named as City_Id and a string property named  as City_Name. Then pass initialize and pass a list of this class to the datacontractjsonserializer.

Comment: I have tried this:
            public class city
    {
        public city_info city_info { get; set; }    
    
    }
    public class city_info
    {
        public string city_id { get; set; }
        public int city_name { get; set; }

    }

But it doesnot work cause I can't define a '0' named function.

Comment: I have tried this much already but this shows invalid cast exception after cities = (List<City>)serializer.ReadObject(theObjectToBeDeserialized); .Thats the reason I asked you tell me class